# Sparse Array using HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, collections, maps

Sparse Array

There is a collection of input strings and a collection of query strings. For each query string, determine how many times it occurs in the list of input strings.
For example, given input strings=['ab','ab','abc'] and queries=['ab','abc','bc'] we find 2 instances of 'ab',1  of 'ab' and  0 of 'bc'. For each query, we add an element to our return array, result=[2,1,0] .

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sparse-arrays/problem?isFullScreen=true

I tried this solution but it passes 3 test cases only.

```
static int[] matchingStrings(String[] strings, String[] queries) {
        int[] result_arr=new int[queries.length];
        HashMap<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<queries.length;i++)
        {
            map.put(queries[i],i);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++)
        {
            if(map.containsKey(strings[i]))
            {
                int index=map.get(strings[i]);
                System.out.println(index);
                result_arr[index]+=1;
            }
        }
        return result_arr;
    }
```

Comment: Use the following input to your algorithm: strings = {"ab", "ab", "abc"} and queries = {"ab", "ab"}

Comment: it outputs 2 and 0, but it has to be 2 and 2 I think @emil . thanks, got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will break in case when your `queries` array has duplicate values.

So, instead of creating hashmap of `queries` array you should create it for `strings` array. This is because for each query , you need to check how many time that string is present in `strings` array.
Currently in case of duplicate value in your `queries` array your hashmap itself does not get populated properly.

Here is the updated code :

```
static int[] matchingStrings(String[] strings, String[] queries) {
        int[] result_arr=new int[queries.length];
        HashMap<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++)
        {
            if(map.containsKey(strings[i])) {
                map.put(strings[i], map.get(strings[i])+1);
            } else {
                map.put(strings[i],1);
            }
        } 
        for(int i=0;i<queries.length;i++)
        {
            if(map.containsKey(queries[i]))
            {
                result_arr[i]+=map.get(queries[i]);
            }
        }
        return result_arr;

    }
```

Comment: Instead of `for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++)
        {
            if(map.containsKey(strings[i])) {
                map.put(strings[i], map.get(strings[i])+1);
            } else {
                map.put(strings[i],1);
            }
        }` you can use `for(String s: strings) map.merge(s,1, Integer::num);`. And in the second loop, you can replace `if(map.containsKey(queries[i]))
            {
                result_arr[i]+=map.get(queries[i]);
            }` with the simpler `result_arr[i]+=map.getOrDefault(queries[i], 0);`